# Rollback the transaction if any query fails

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, transactions

I'm trying to execute multiple update SQL queries in a list. And if any of the query fails at any point, I want to rollback all previous query updations.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = sa.create_engine(r'mssql+pyodbc://<IP>\SQLEXPRESS/<db>?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
queries = ['query1', 'query2', 'query3', '......'] #Query List
# ToDo: if any query execution from the list fails, rollback all the previous query execution
```

Please help. I already tried multiple answers from SO. But couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a context manager:

```py
with Session(engine) as sess, sess.begin():
    # sess.execute() one or more queries
```

The context manager will commit the changes if there were no errors, otherwise it will do a rollback.

Comment: but the problem is if 1st & 2nd queries passed but 3rd failed then we need to rollback 1st and 2nd both .

Comment: `sess.begin()` begins the transaction. If there is an error it will roll back the entire transaction.

Comment: So I can use `sess.execute(query[i])` in loop and it would take care on its own ?

Comment: I suggest that you build yourself a little test and see for yourself.